# How to force td in different table rows to be inline?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm adding some CSS styles to a HTML code I haven't written, and there are some contents that are inside table td's in different rows, but I need all the td's to be in the same line.

Basically, I need something like...

```
+-------+
| a | b |
+---+---+
| c | d |
+-------+
```

... to look like...

```
+---------------+
| a | b | c | d |
+---------------+
```

Comment: I do not believe this is possible.  Can you modify the HTML itself in any way?

Comment: Nope, I can't. I'm using an external service in which is only allowed to add CSS styles.

Comment: c'mon! by default table td is like this, no need to add any css! [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96mww8xr/)

Comment: @jiff I think OP has many table rows (`tr`)

Comment: @Aziz I never saw table td with more or less `tr` like that, sure something is wrong with OP code. as you see [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96mww8xr/1/) nothing changed.

Comment: @jiff nothing wrong. OP wanted the rows to be in same line -> https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/y6Lwp8u9/1/

Comment: now i get it,. I think `a b c d` made me confused. I thought `a b c d` are `td` in one row. thanks for clarify. @Aziz

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this (https://jsfiddle.net/gvLbq9rn/)

CSS:

```
tr {display: table-cell;}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This gives the best result :

```
tr, td {
    display: inline;
}
```

---

#### Demo

```css
tr, td {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jphxkr45/))

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Table</title>
  <style>
    tr{
      display: inline;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Another way, by giving `tr` display `inline`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a smaple table which looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>TH1</th>
    <th>TH2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then the resultant will be like:

| TH1 | Th2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |

But you want something which is in different 'tr' to be in one line makes it messy.
You will be getting something like this if you try to do it with css

```
tr {display : inline;}
```

| TH1 | TH2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

And this looks really messy better use [Grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) for such cases!